# how to sum values of third column where col1 col2 have duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Below The image is a demo dataset

[image]

The Desired Result is like this, what pandas functions should  I use here  [image]

Please Read the headings in Image 2 to get a better understanding of my question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Use groupby with aggregation

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg({'col3': ['count', 'sum']})
```